# I cant add Issue to redmine (rest-api)

Tags: rest, redmine, redmine-api

I try create new Issue according to site:
http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_Issues#Creating-an-issue

I try send json via post method. (using postman -plugin for chrome)

Post query: [my-domain]/redmine/issues.json

```
{
  "issue": {
    "project_id": 1,     // my project has different number.
    "subject": "Example",
    "priority_id": 4
  }
}
```

as a result it gaves me 404 I cant understand why.

I tried also use this query for post method
my-domain/redmine/projects/[my-project-name]/issues.xml

result: 
Subject can't be blank ---- but i gave it subject title!!

I dont know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the api key of redmine account to url, because the operation of 'create', 'update' and 'delete' need authorization except showing issue(GET).

The url should be like this:

```
http://redmine.example.com/issues.json?key=a83bf179b33e2403385b4ab61da469b2f369f3a7
```

You can get the api key of redmine account by following some steps:

1 Log in redmine system on website;

2 Click *My Account* on the top right corner of redmine;

3 Get the api key below the *My Account* button by a click on *show api key*, copy it.